# Create CodePipeline Notification Rule using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm building a CodePipeline stack using CloudFormation. Everything works flawlessly. One element I am unable to add is the Notification rule using CloudFormation Template and I cannot find any documentation on it apart from the console method.

I tried adding a `NotificationArn` like this but this doesn't work as I found out it is specific to `Manuapproval` action.

```
CodePipelineSNSTopic:
Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
Properties:
  Subscription:
    - Endpoint: !Ref Email
      Protocol: email
.
.
.
- Name: S3Source
      Actions:
        - Name: TemplateSource
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Source
            Owner: AWS
            Provider: S3
            Version: '1'
          Configuration:
            S3Bucket: !Ref 'S3Bucket'
            S3ObjectKey: !Ref 'SourceS3Key'
            NotificationArn: !Ref CodePipelineSNSTopic
          OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: TemplateSource
          RunOrder: '1'
```

Is there a documentation that I am unable to find? Please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CodePipeline notifiacations are handled and setup using

- [AWS::CodeStarNotifications::NotificationRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codestarnotifications-notificationrule.html)

The events supported and which should be used in the rule are described in:

- [Events for Notification Rules on Pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar-notifications/latest/userguide/concepts.html#events-ref-pipeline)

Comment: @RedBottle No problem. I was also scratching my head when they introduced these notifications :-)

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for this too. How difficult it is for AWS to just add a sentence in codepipeline cfn to point us to codestar...